# How would I fix this to not be an array of reference?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, reference, declaration

Preface: Yes I am aware of the inconsistency in function definitions, I am in the process of trying to write the thing.

Specifically in line

```
void renderScreen(char& currentMap[100][100], int& screenX, int& screenY)
```

The `char& currentMap[100][100]` creates an array of references. How would I call a separate char variable based on a 2D map (array of chars) into this function without making an array of references?

Context:

```
#include <iostream>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500 //win2000, must be before #windows.h
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include "declarations.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int screenX, int screenY)
{
    SetConsoleDisplayMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE, 0);

    while (!quit) {
        
    }
    return 0;
}

void renderScreen(char& currentMap[100][100], int& screenX, int& screenY) {
    int xi; int yi;

    for (xi = 0; xi < screenX; xi++) {
        for (yi = 0; yi < screenY; yi++) {
            screen += currentMap[xi][yi];
        }
        cout << screen << endl;
        screen.clear();
    }

}
```

.h file

```
#pragma once
//fns
void renderScreen(char& currentTile, int& screenX, int& screenY);

//vars
string screen;
bool quit = false;
int i; int j;
int screenX; int screenY;
char currentMap[100][100];
char currentTile;
```

Comment: Why not wrap the data in a struct? E.g struct map? then you can pass a reference to that around it will have a clear name and type throughout your code. (and probably add some usable methods too).

Comment: I could, but an array behooves 2D map structure design. Struct would make building and interpretation of that a little more difficult.

Comment: @PepijnKramer gives the right solution, but, syntactically, `char (&currentMap)[100][100]` is a reference to an array of arrays of `char`.

Comment: Oh, ok I gotcha so just "char& currentMap" would be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any sense in the second and third parameter declarations declared as references

```
void renderScreen(char& currentMap[100][100], int& screenX, int& screenY);
```

because within the function the original objects used as arguments are not changed within the function. So the function could be declared at least like (if to ignore the incorrect declaration of the first parameter)

```
void renderScreen(char& currentMap[100][100], size_t screenX, size_t screenY);
```

Also there is no great sense to pass the array by reference.

The function could be declared like

```
void renderScreen(const char ( *currentMap )[100], size_t screenX, size_t screenY);
```

If to pass the array by reference then the function declaration can look like

```
void renderScreen(const char ( &currentMap )[100][100], size_t screenX, size_t screenY);
```

Comment: Yes you're right about that, got a bit cought up in ref I suppose.